# How can I change the color of the character I've searched?

Tags: vb.net, fonts, colors

I have this machine problem that would allow user to enter a paragraph in TextBox1. Then asks user to enter a character on TextBox2 to be searched on TextBox1(paragraph). The last thing I need to do is...change the color of the searched character in TextBox1 when the executeBUTTON is clicked. Is it possible? Because I've searched like a thousand times and couldn't find any answer. I'm using only TextBox and found some answers that says change it to RichTextBox, but I don't know how (if it's possible to do).

Comment: You will need to use a RichTextBox as your searching mentioned, a standard TextBox has one Font, Style and Color. Just use a RichTextBox from your toolbox instead of a TextBox.